# Linking errors although I have included libs file properly

Tags: visual-studio, glew

```
***1>  LINK : D:\users\atulit\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\simplegl\Debug\SimpleGL.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Windowclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
1>Windowclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindBuffer
1>Windowclass.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
1>D:\users\atulit\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\simplegl\Debug\SimpleGL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========***
```

Why am I getting these linking errors though I have set up the libraries properly?

Comment: You should include how you set things up

Answer (score 0):

Your project is missing definitions for the specified functions, which are defined in the glew library. In addition to the general causes listed in the link below, my guesses are:

1) The glew library is not included. Please make sure to include (1) the library (glew32.lib) to "Additional Dependencies", and (2) the library path to the "Additional Library Dependencies".

2) You can put the command line options to link against glew. Place '-lGLEW' or '-lglew32' into your command line options. (Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options).

3) Although it is a warning (not an error that prevents the build), it might be related to the colliding library options (i.e., some built with /MD some and some are not). This might end up confusing the linker too, so you can try adding /NODEFAULT:lib as written in the warning.

More information about the linker error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx

Comment: i have included glew32.lib in additional dependencies and added those thingy in command line ,still getting errors

Comment: Is it the same error? Can you clean and build the project again?

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the answer to my problem the thing is i have to call glInit() after making window context!!!